# Docker container names

Tags: ruby-on-rails, docker, docker-compose

I'm using Docker on Rails project. I found only one way to reliably link services between each other, i. e. specifying container_name in `docker-compose.yml`:

```
version: '3'
services:
  db:
    container_name: sociaball_db
    ...
  web:
    container_name: sociaball_web
    ...
  sphinx:
    container_name: sociaball_sphinx
    ...
```

So now I can write something like this in `database.yml` and stop worrying about, say, database container randomly changing its name from `db` to `db_1`:

```
common: &common
  ...
  host: sociaball_db
```

However, I can only run three containers at the same time. Whenever I try to run `docker-container up` if some containers aren't down it will raise an error.

```
ERROR: for sociaball_db  Cannot create container for service db: Conflict. The container name "/sociaball_db" is already in use by container "ee787c06db7b2a0205e3c1e552b6a5496545a78fe12d942fb792b27f3c38769c". You have to remove (or rename) that container to be able to reuse that name.
```

It is very inconvenient. It often forces explicitly deleting all the containers just to make sure they have no opportunity to break. Is there a way around that?

Comment: You shouldn't need to manually specify `container_name:`; the containers should be reachable from each other using the service tag in the `docker-compose.yml` file as host names (_e.g._, `host: db`).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When running several containers from one compose file, there will be a default network where all containers are attached to (if not specified differently).

There is no need to reference a container by its container or hostname as docker-compose automatically sets up some dns service discovery where each docker-compose service can be resolved by its service name (the key used one level below `services:`.

So your service called `web` can reach your database using the name `db`. No need to specify a container name for this use case. For more details please see the [docker docs on networking](https://docs.docker.com/compose/networking/) that also demonstrates a rails app accessing a database.